# How do I get antialiasing in LibGDX with the LWJGL3 backend?

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl3

Updated to the LWJGL3 backend for LibGDX to for controller connect / disconnect functionality and access to geometry shaders and I'd rather not go back. There used to be a "samples" field in the LWJGLApplicationConfiguration object for setting antialiasing, but it no longer exists in LWJGL3ApplicationConfiguration. (Oh, and I'm only targeting Desktop)

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about, there is a samples field https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl3/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl3/Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration.java

Comment: Ah, it does indeed exist but is package private, so can't be modified directly.

Comment: You shouldn't but you can. You even said the keyword, "package private". You can just create a wrapper and put it in the same package. You can also use reflection and stuff. Though in this case, there's a setter for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setBackBufferConfig` on the LWJGL3ApplicationConfig. The last parameter is the amount of samples.

```
public void setBackBufferConfig(int r, int g, int b, int a, int depth, int stencil, int samples)
```